# Sync a Sharepoint list from GCP

Tags: list, api, data, database-connection

Is it possible to create a Sharepoint that has APIs to synchronise the data with data stored on Google Cloud Platform?

I would ideally like to implement an API to keep the data in the Sharepoint list up to date by sync-ing down from GCP. I would also like to implement an API that pushed modifications made in the Sharepoint list back up to the GCP data.

Is any of this possible on Sharepoint?

Comment: SharePoint on-prem or SharePoint Online?

Comment: Using Sharepoint Online, but I also have access to the Sharepoint Desktop client

Comment: (I work is a larger business that has SharePoint Online capability - though I'm not sure whether this is deployed via SharePoint Online or whether the data is managed via on premises servers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also have access to the Sharepoint Desktop client

Is this the OneDrive Sync client?

> Is it possible to create a Sharepoint that has APIs to synchronise the data with data stored on Google Cloud Platform?

SharePoint has APIs for just about anything you want to do with content!

So, assuming by sync, you want the same files to be available in both systems... Or more likely, a one-way sync from a "master" library to a "clone" library...

Options:

- Use the OneDrive sync client to sync a library's content to a local PC or server, and then, assuming that it exists, use the Google sync client to sync to the same location on that PC.
- Write your own sync client (C#/Visual Studio or just about any other toolset) that monitors the date of last change in one system and copies the files to the other. SharePoint has REST APIs that can do the queries and the file copies. I would assume Google has something similar.
- Use one of the third party solutions... do a web search for "sync sharepoint library with google drive"

SharePoint REST API: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service